# How to bring text and button on same line in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

[how to bring the text and button on same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWPqO.png) 
This is the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <h4>Edit Post</h4> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline- 
      block;">Add New</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 `d-inline-block` class on the heading...

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <h4 class="d-inline-block">Edit Post</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
</div>
```

Optionally use `align-middle` to vertically align with the button.

https://www.codeply.com/go/F2uHcAPvmx